# how can i have only navigation in my left column

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

all i want is a navigation on my left column:

```
home
search
...
```

so whatever template i choose for new website, it always shows this Libraries, Site Pages, Lists, and etc...

how can i create that navigation and get rid of those links in a sharepoint way? i mean less coding and more designing.

note: i use sharepoint 2010 and i already know that i can inherit a new master form "minimal.master" and roll my own css and layout by typing code in the code view mode of sharepoint designer. so i wonder if sharepoint has no automation for that!

Comment: AFAIK - its master page and css for this type of branding, you may decide to use SharePoint Designer for this but try keep it clean and come up with a good master page and alternate css as you have already mentioned.

Comment: but wait, what about avoid typings? if i wanna do that then i can just use visual studio instead! whats the point of designer then? since it doesn't have a good intellisence...